# <ruby> with text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I am unable to get `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work with `<ruby/>` tags that have contained `<rt/>` tags. The sample below shows that ellipsis works, but when there is an `<rt/>` element, it stops working. Is there a way for this to work?

```css
body {
  width: 100px;
}

ruby,
.item,
.container {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.t3 ruby,
.t4 ruby {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container t1">
    <div class="item">
      <ruby>This is some base text.<rt>This is ruby text.</rt></ruby>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container t2">
    <div class="item">
      This is some text.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container t3">
    <div class="item">
      <ruby>This is text in a ruby tag.</ruby>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container t4">
    <div class="item">
      <ruby>This is some other base text.<rt>This is other ruby text.</rt></ruby>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: am pretty sure this is due to the nature of ruby element ... i don't have the answer but it may be here : https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ruby-1/

Answer (score 0):

Ellipsizing text for ruby works just fine using the traditional CSS snippets. However, several browsers, including Chrome, have problems with it. If you want a working browser, use IE11 or Firefox.

See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=817561